# Permission denied for only a single file in a directory as root user on an ext3 filesystem under RAIDiator OS

Tags: files, permissions, root, ext3

I have a ReadyNAS box named "storage" that I believe is based on Debian.   I can ssh into it as root.   I'm trying to reconfigure the webserver, but I'm running into a file permissions problem that I just don't understand.   I can't do anything with `/etc/frontview/apache/apache.pem` even as root!  It doesn't appear to have any special permissions compared to other files in the same directory and I can work with those.

```
storage:~# whoami 
root
storage:~# cd /etc/frontview/apache/   
storage:/etc/frontview/apache# ls -lah apache.pem*         
-rw-------    1 admin    admin        4.0k Jul 10  2013 apache.pem
-rw-------    1 admin    admin        4.0k Jun  9 05:57 apache.pem.2017-02-04
-rw-------    1 admin    admin        1.5k Jun  9 05:57 apache.pem.orig
storage:/etc/frontview/apache# touch apache.pem            
touch: creating `apache.pem': Permission denied
storage:/etc/frontview/apache# touch apache.pem.2017-02-04 
storage:/etc/frontview/apache# rm -f apache.pem
rm: cannot unlink `apache.pem': Operation not permitted
```

What is so special about this file that it can't be touched?  I can't delete it.   I can't change the permissions on it.  I can't change the owner of it.

The directory seems to be fine.  It has space left, it isn't mounted read-only.  In fact I can edit other files in the same directory.

```
# ls -ld /etc/frontview/apache
drwxr-xr-x    8 admin    admin        4096 Jun  9 05:44 /etc/frontview/apache
# df /etc/frontview/apache
Filesystem           1k-blocks      Used     Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/hdc1            2015824        504944   1510880   26% /
```

Comment: Please also show the output of `ls -ld /etc/frontview/apache` and `df /etc/frontview/apache`. Maybe the folder is on a disk space mounted `ro`?

Comment: I added that info to the question.  It all looks fine to me.   In any case, if that were the problem, I wouldn't think I could edit every other file in that directory.

Comment: @RunCMD  I added more specific information to the title and tags.  The filesystem is listed as ext3, so ext3 would appear to to support immutable:  `# mount`: `/dev/hdc1 on / type ext3 (rw,noatime)`

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag. Yes, [ext3 supports the immutable bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) and [apparently even ext2](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-server-hacks/0596004613/ch01s09.html). Still, it's depnding on the file system implementation...

Comment: Solaris doesn't support ext3 nor ARM cpu's so that's probably not based on Solaris.

Comment: It appears to be Linux based and used for consumer NAS products by netgear.  The most info I could find on it was a review of one on a mac website.  But what I found curious, was that their initial product release used a SPARC CPU, and now ARM.  However, I could find no information on which chip.

Comment: I removed Solaris from the question.   On further reading it may be based on Debian Etch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found the problem.   The "immutable" attribute was set on that file.   `ls` doesn't show it.   You need a different command to see it:

```
# lsattr apache.pem*
----i--------- apache.pem
-------------- apache.pem.2017-02-04
-------------- apache.pem.orig
```

Once I remove the immutable bit, I can edit that file:

```
# chattr -i apache.pem
# touch apache.pem
```

Comment: I clicked on this question in the "hot network questions" to tell you to check the extended-attributes, but I guess you already did.  (IDK why GNU `ls` doesn't have an option to list attributes.  I forget, but maybe even the system call for querying them isn't portable, so it was probably easier just to implement them in a separate utility.)

Comment: @PeterCordes  I agree.   I'm sure I set that bit after Googling something like "stop upgrade from overwriting file", but that was years ago and I clearly forgot doing so.  It would be nice if `ls` showed the that bit, or if any of the the other commands I used had more helpful (and specific) error messages about why the permissions were denied.

Comment: All `touch` knows is that the system call it attempted (`open("apache.pem", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|..., 0666)`) failed  with `EACCESS`.  (Use `strace -efile touch apache.pem` to see the file-related system calls it makes).  As [the man page for that system call says](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), there are many possible reasons for EACCESS, and many of them involve parent directories rather than the file itself.  Writing code to *accurately* deduce why a system call returned the error it did would be extremely hard, since different filesystems and OSes are different...

Comment: Anyway, the universal convention is that when something fails, you look up the error string for the error code (`errno`) and print that.  (Using the C standard library `perror` function, or equivalent).  This is one of the rare cases where that isn't always enough of a hint for the user to quickly find the problem, but most of the time it works very well.  (Especially when combined with `strace` in case there's any doubt about exactly which operation produced the error.)  It's not perfect, but it could be *much* worse (cf. MS Windows where at best you get an error code to google.)

Comment: Was just playing around with `chattr +i`, and noticed that `rm foo` (without `-f`) prompts: `rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘foo’`.  Because  `faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/tmp/foo", W_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`.  POSIX requires `rm` to prompt by default before removing write-protected files, and , which is why it checks in the first place.  So you would have gotten a big clue faster if you hadn't used `rm -f`.  :/  `access(3)` asks the kernel to check permissions as if it was really opening for write, so it picks up ACLs and attributes.

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually have that in my question.  On this solaris based system the message isn't nearly as helpful.  ;(

Comment: No, you don't.  You only show `rm -f`, which doesn't **prompt** `rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘foo’?` before saying `rm: cannot remove ‘foo’: Operation not permitted` if you type `y`.  (I accidentally missed copying the `?` at the end in the prev comment, sorry).  The fact that `rm` pops up a prompt instead of just trying and failing is the big clue that something is unusual, especially after checking the Unix file permissions.